# How to append div in angular js depending upon condition (ANGULAR JS)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a div that repeats all of the values in my messages array. I'm having trouble figuring out how to append the next message.content to the same div (not to create new one) if the next message.id is equal to the previous message.id

My code's logic look like this but this isn't really it.

```
  <div ng-repeat="message in messages" ng-class="{'sent': userId == 
   message.id, 'received': userId != message.id}">           
    <div class="message">        
      //message.content goes here          
      //I dont want to create a new div if the next 
        message.id is equal to the previous message.id
      //Planning to just append the content here
      //If its not equal then repeat the div as usual
      //Please help T_T          
    </div>
  </div>
```

The structure of my messages array contains id, content, and date

Comment: I dont want to group everything separately, i only want to group them if the it matches the previous message.id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*As per question you don't want to create new div just skip the loop if previous and current ids are equal.*

So a simple use of `ng-if` can solve your problem., because it create new DOM element rather than just showing or hiding. Like : `ng-if="message.id !== messages[$index-1].id"`,

and it can be used directly on html so `messages[-1].id` won't crash on html.

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bm5hpw5y/).

Updated [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5h93fkmu/), which check for any existing previous `id` and append text if any further `id` matches existence one.

Comment: I dont want to skip it, just wanted to append the current processed message's content to the previously created div if their ids are identical

Comment: @RichCuer: I've created this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5h93fkmu/), which checks if any `id` exist previously upto `currentid till [n-1].id` and also append text if `currentid` matched upto till `[n+1].id`. I updated answer too.

Comment: yey thanks youre the only who got what I wanted to happen, the only problem is my ID's are not integers, they're strings like names

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Javascript

```
   $scope.checkMessage = function($index) {

      if($index > 0) {
         return $scope.messages[$index - 1].id == $scope.messages[$index].id
      }
      return true;

   }
```

HTML

```
<div data-ng-if="checkMessage($index)">

     // if ids are equal

</div>

<div data-ng-if="!checkMessage($index)">

     // if ids are not equal

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`groupBy` Angular filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) to group your data on message.id:

```js
angular.module('app', ['angular.filter'])
  .controller('MainController', function($scope) { 
    $scope.messages = [
      {id: 1, date: '01/12/1993', content: 'Hello'},
      {id: 2, date: '11/12/2017', content: 'Morning'},
      {id: 1, date: '05/08/2016', content: 'See you soon'},
      {id: 2, date: '22/01/1998', content: 'Bye'},
      {id: 3, date: '21/09/1932', content: 'Thanks'}
    ];
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.4.7/angular-filter.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController">     
  <ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in messages | groupBy: 'id'">
    Message ID: {{key}}
    <li ng-repeat="m in value">
      Content: {{m.date}} - {{m.content}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont want to group everything separately, i only want to group them if it's message id matches the previous message.id :(

Answer (score 0):

2 ways data binding does it for you, if you need some condition, create a new array and loop through that, to change the view, simply `push` to your array and the view get updated... if you want to check the message.id be equal, simply use ng-show, to show or hide, something like this:

```
<div>

   <div ng-repeat="message in messages" ng-class="{'sent': userId == 
   message.id, 'received': userId != message.id}">

     <div class="message">

    <div ng-show="message.id === messages[$index-1].id" class="message">
       show this message
    </div

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This isn't the answer Im looking for :/

Comment: Can you clarify your question please? you mean you want previous message.id? let refine the code

Comment: I just want to append the next message.content to the previous div if the current processed message by the ng-repeat has an id that is identical to the previous message.id

Comment: I dont want to create a new div ;(

Comment: It's not jQuery, just update your Model and your data get updated automatically in View, let me update my answer for you

Answer (score -1):

You can take a look ng-if.

```html
<div>
  <div ng-repeat="message in messages" ng-class="{'sent': userId == 
   message.id, 'received': userId != message.id}">
    <div class="message" ng-if="condition">        
      //message.content goes here          
      //I dont want to create a new div if the next 
        message.id is equal to the previous message.id
      //Planning to just append the content here
      //If its not equal then repeat the div as usual
      //Please help T_T          
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't solve anything, this involves more than a couple of if's

Comment: @RichCuer maybe you must be more specific, all responses are equals!