# How to embed a JavaScript if clause into a HTML code

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I want to embed a JavaScript if clause into a HTML code.There are two buttons named `success` and `danger` those are separated by a `if` clause.  I tried for it as following manner.

```
<script>
    if (1 < 18) {
</script>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-rounded">Success</button>
<script>
    }
    else{
</script>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded">Danger</button>
<script>
    }
</script>
```

But it did not work in properly. Then what should I do for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109178/how-to-append-div-in-angular-js-depending-upon-condition-angular-js

Comment: Actually a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/35163009/215552, which is for Angular, not AngularJS.

Comment: Are you actually doing this in Angular? You used the tag, but there isn't any Angular-specific code in your example, and it generally doesn't use `<script>` tags.

Comment: @John Montgomery Yes I'm using angular.  This is the `component.html` file. How I use a if clause for separate those buttons

Comment: Use `*ngIf` instead.

Comment: Just based on this question, I would suggest that you read the tutorial, using `*ngIf` is such a basic thing to know, so to get the most out of angular I **strongly** suggest you read the tutorial: https://angular.io/tutorial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few different ways you can do this in Angular. The simplest change would be to just use `*ngIf`:

```js
<button *ngIf="1 < 18" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-rounded">Success</button>
<button *ngIf="1 >= 18" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded">Danger</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write the HTML code with the JavaScript, see below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var i = 0;
window.onload = function(){
if (i == 0)
{
     document.getElementById('somearea').innerHTML = '<input type="button" value="Some Value 1"/>';
}
else
{
     document.getElementById('somearea').innerHTML = '<input type="button" value="Some Value 2"/>';
}
}
    </script>
```